# Suppress a duplicate row in SQL Server 2005 based on condition and list remaining rows that don't meet the condition

Tags: sql, duplicates, hide, row, conditional-statements

I'm currently running into an issue where I'm getting duplicate rows and here is what I need to do. I need to suppress a duplicate row when a condition is met and list the remaining rows when the condition is not met.

```
SELECT
    SHPMNT_NO, TOT_WEIGHT, HAZARD
FROM       
    dbo.DVUD_Prep
```

Current output:

```
SHPMNT_NO  TOT_WEIGHT  HAZARD
---------  ----------  ------
000133701  100
000133702  120
000133703  461
000133703  461        Y
000133704  100
000133705  122
```

Desired output: (not listing shipment# 000133703 which is duplicate row where Hazard <> N.
I've done multiple searches in here and I can't find a similar scenario.

```
SHPMNT_NO  TOT_WEIGHT  HAZARD
---------  ----------  ------
000133701  100
000133702  120
000133703  461         Y
000133704  100
000133705  122
```

Sorry I don't know how to display text or data in a yellow block. help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: post the query you are using to get the output :)

Comment: This my first post(Question) on Stackoverflow, so I'm getting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT SHPMNT_NO, TOT_WEIGHT, MAX(HAZARD) as HAZARD
FROM myTable
GROUP BY SHPMNT_NO, TOT_WEIGHT
```

Comment: great this exactly what I was looking for. I never thought of using the MAX() function and then grouping the duplicate rows after that. I was going on totally different route that is good for identifying the dups but it would not list everything else. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

If Hazard is blank or 'Y' then you can use `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` to get your desired output:

```
SELECT SHPMNT_NO,  TOT_WEIGHT, MAX(HAZARD) 'HAZARD'
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY SHPMNT_NO, TOT_WEIGHT
```

This will also work if Hazard is 'Y' or 'N'.

Comment: your method worked as well even though I didn't have N's in that column. It's either a 'Y' or NULL. Thanks!

Comment: Aww shucks, 2nd mouse got the cheese.  ;)